# Publishing a website online: What verb is most natural?

Tags: verbs, internet

What is the most natural verb to use for the equivalent of "publishing" a website online?

1. Create a website
2. Launch a website
3. Open a website
4. Start a website

Comment: "Publish" is frequently used, if the site will have the nature of a periodical.

Comment: as HotLicks suggests, it very much **depends on what sort of web site** or business it is.  (Recall too that very often the literal 'web site' is only a small part of an overall online business.)

Comment: (for example, you'd never say "what do I do, I publish an online stockbrokerage web site..."  You probably wouldn't say "I publish a social media company".  Whereas you probably would say "I publish a car magazine web site..")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a new website altogether, you might consider:

> Establish a website.
>   Inaugurate a website.
>   Introduce a website.
>   Launch a website.
>   Spawn a website.

If it's an update to an existing website, you could consider:

> Deploy [a new version of] a website.
>   Improve a website.
>   Publish [an update to] a website.
>   Recreate a website.
>   Reinvent a website.

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2 are about equal. (3 & 4 don't sound natural.)

"Create" conveys more the technical part of building and designing the website.

"Launch" might give a more business/marketing sound, as in "launched a business."

Answer (score 0):

> Deploy

Google is deploying a new version of Gmail today.